# Django design model - when a data of status field changes, remaining models status change with it

Tags: django, model

Its my first time trying django as my first programming project.

I have a hierarchy structure of Company -> Business -> Outlets using foreign key.

I would like to know is there anyway to structured it in a way where the Company status is saved as inactive status, the remaining business, outlets models that will be triggered as inactive status.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Common_Info(models.Model):
    """(Common description)"""
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=120)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    address_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=False)
    registration_no. = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=False)
    gst_no. = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    telphone_no. = models.CharField(max_legth=15, null=False)
    fax_no. = models.CharField(max_legth=15, null=True)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=254,null=False)
    """(Status choice)"""
    Active_Status = 1
    Inactive_Status = 0
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (Active_Status, 'Active'),
        (Inactive_Status, 'Inactive'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=Active_Status)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    create_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Company(Common_Info):
    """(Company additional description)"""
    gst_no. = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name ='Company'
        verbose_name_plural = "Companies"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Company"

class Business(Common_Info):
    """(Business description)"""
    parent=models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gst_no. = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name ='Business'
        verbose_name_plural = "Businesses"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Business"

class Outlet(Common_Info):
    outlet_code = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    business_name = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Outlet"
```

Is there something similar to cascade on delete or other more elegant way of extending such a function across other apps in the project.

Comment: You could handle it in your view, and add a check to see if the company is inactive, before saving, to update the status for business and outlets. What view are you using to handle the status change for the Company?

Comment: Should the user be able to change a Business or Outlet status independantly of the Company status ? If yes, are there restriction on which status is allowed, depending on the company status ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. user should be able to change the status independently, just that when the parent level is inactive, the child should be inactive automatically. Next scenario is when the parent is saved as active, the child should remains inactive until user decide whether they should be active or not.

Comment: @YuanfengLin please see my answer. Its updated accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @ruddra thanks for the help. the code let me understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any direct support in ORM. But you can override the `save()` method to update the related the outlets and business. You can use [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/) to fetch business and outlets. Here is an example:

```
class Company(Common_Info):
    """(Company additional description)"""
    gst_no. = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name ='Company'
        verbose_name_plural = "Companies"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Company"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.status == 0:
             self.business_set.update(status=self.status)
             self.outlet_set.update(status=self.status)
```

Comment: Just a last thought; the OP actually only asked how to _deactivate_ related outlets and business when the company is deactivated, not to (re) activate them when the company is activated (yes I know I advised to remove the test on `self.status` a couple minutes ago...)

Comment: I think that change can be simply implemented by OP. But lets not overthink, let the OP decide on what he/she wants when Company is re-activated :) .

Comment: indeed - just wanted to make clear that this solution doesn't _exactly_ match the OP's question ;-)

Comment: Hi, just want to know if it is also possible if outlets's status is active, the business and company status be  updated to active using the model.save methods? or i will have no choice but to use post-signal.

Comment: I think u can use either one of them. If you are using model save, then override the outlet save method.

Comment: @ruddra would the following helps:   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Business, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.status == 0:
            self.outlet_set.update(status=self.status)
        if self.status == 1:
            company.objects.filter(pk=self.company).update(status=self.status